# How to map data coming dynamically into the designed table individually in respective form fields using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My data in the table is coming from back-end or user can manually enter the values in the table. Now my question is 'how to map those values again into the form, from which user was able to enter values into the table using jquery'? This back mapping of data from table to form is done on click of edit link which is present in front of every entry of my data in the table.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown>a:after {
    display: none;
}
.glyph-ok-size, .glyph-remove-size {
    font-size: 15px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add_edit_panel").hide();
    $("#addNew").click(function() {
      $(".add_edit_panel").slideToggle();
    });
});

function edit(paramID){
    $(".add_edit_panel").slideDown();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <cu:secured hasPermission="CORE_CUSTOMER_DATES_CREATE"
        var="canCreateOrgDates"></cu:secured>
    <cu:secured hasPermission="CORE_CUSTOMER_DATES_UPDATE"
        var="canUpdateOrgDates"></cu:secured>
    <cu:taskView taskFlowData="${taskFlowData}"
        taskFlowDefinition="${taskFlowDefinition}" id="dateRange"
        renderTasks="false"
        title="task.title.organization.daterange" 
        tasks="${taskFlowData.availableTasks}">
    </cu:taskView>
       <div class="row">
            <form action="save.action" method="post">               
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="panel add_edit_panel">
                                <div class="panel-heading">${fmt:message('dateRange.panel.add.edit') }</div>
                           <core:text name="orgDateObj.periodName"
                                     label="${fmt:message('org.daterange.name') }"
                                     required="false"
                                     maxlength="20"
                                     placeholder="${fmt:message('org.daterange.name') }">
                            </core:text> 
                            <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <core:date id="startDate" name="orgDateObj.startDate" label="${fmt:message('org.daterange.startdate')}" 

                                     placeholder="${fmt:message('org.daterange.startdate')}"   
                                     primary="false" required="true" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <core:date id="endDate" name="orgDateObj.endDate" label="${fmt:message('org.daterange.enddate')}" 

                                      placeholder="${fmt:message('org.daterange.enddate')}"   
                                      primary="false" required="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label class="default" style="float=left"><core:checkbox 
                                      name="orgDateObj.isDefault" id="isDefault"
                                      label="${fmt:message('org.daterange.defaultdate')}"
                                      checked="true" indicator="true" 
                                      disabled="false" 
                                      title="${fmt:message('org.daterange.describe.defaultdate')}" />
                            </label>
                            <div class="btn-panel-margin">
                                <button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-ar btn-primary" data-allow-dirty="allow">
                                ${fmt:message('button.save')}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </form>             
       </div>
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">${fmt:message('dateRange.panel.listing') }</div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="overflow-x: scroll">
            <table data-grid-sortable class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive sort-display-table">
                <thead>
                     <tr>
                    <th data-column-sortable class="column-md sorted"><fmt:message key="table.date.name"/>
                    <span class="caret column-sort-direction"/>
                    </th>
                    <th data-column-sortable class="column-md"><fmt:message key="table.startdate"/>
                    <span class="caret column-sort-direction"/>
                    </th>
                    <th data-column-sortable class="column-md"><fmt:message key="table.enddate"/>
                    <span class="caret column-sort-direction"/>
                    </th>
                    <th data-column-sortable class="column-sm"><fmt:message key="table.default"/>
                    <span class="caret column-sort-direction"/>
                    </th>
                    <th data-column-sortable class="column-sm"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">
               <c:forEach var="orgDate" items="${orgDates}">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="column-md">${orgDate.periodName}</td>
                        <td class="column-md">${orgDate.startDate}</td>
                        <td class="column-md">${orgDate.endDate}</td>
                        <td class="column-sm">
                        <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${orgDate.isDefault == '1'}">
                               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove glyph-remove-size"></span>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyph-ok-size"></span>
                        </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                        </td>
                        <td class="column-sm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Action<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="pull-right dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" id="editButtonId" onclick="edit(${orgDate.orgDateId})" >
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil margin-right-5"></i>Edit
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" id="deleteButtonId${orgDate.orgDateId}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash margin-right-5"></i>Delete
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                 </c:forEach>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="btn-panel-margin">
                    <button id="addNew" type="button" class="btn btn-ar btn-primary" data-allow-dirty="allow">
                        ${fmt:message('button.addnew')}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyjgh.png)

Comment: The attached image is the layout of my page

Comment: where is edit link...??

Comment: I have seen only image where I didn't found edit

Comment: no I didn't see it......

Comment: you didn't post image...

Comment: Link below the code will show that img @NikhilGhuse

Comment: @Saily do you want the registered form  value just  after registeration at the bottom?

Comment: It is easy when you use jquery-ui datagrid

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know how your data is formed from Database

In jquery use

```
x=0;
 objectdata.forEach(function(value,indexname,arr), thisValue) {
      tabledata['col'+x][indexname]=value;
     x++;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but i want it in jquery @joyson

Comment: K But i want to know how your array formed in jquery atleast for two keys/rows

Answer (score 0):

in edit button give the row index as class and get the value of that row by mapping array index value of 1st row of table equals to array[0] access the array[0] values and place the value of array in form text box i.e

```
  $('#textbox1').val=array[0]['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do stuff like this

```
  $('#edit').onclick(function (){
   $('#name').val=array[0]['name'];
    $('#startDate').val=array[1]['S-Date'];
    $('#endDate').val=array[2]['E-Date'];
   $('#checkbox').val=array[3]['Checkval'];
   });
```